# Wordpress can't find style.css

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wp development and I'm used to have a custom development environment using gulp. So I have a folder called development where I store all my development folders and files. In this folder, I have index.php, functions.php and style.css. However, wp says it can't find the stylesheet. The absolute path to the file is builds/development/style.css etc, however the relative path of style.css (to the index.php) should be good enough, right? How to fix this?

image of my file structure http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=2452032environment.png

Comment: Are you trying to create a wordpress theme? A theme must reside in `wp-content/themes` and consist of certain files. In addition the `styles.css` file must contain certain meta data. See this for details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Well, as you could see in the image, i have that all covered... when i place the style.css in the absolute base folder it works, but that is not the solution.

Comment: styles.css needs to be in the root of your theme, not in a sub folder. My advice is to create an empty styles.css in the root of your theme (`wp-content/themes/Blog`) and just put the required meta data in it, and an @import line for your actual css file.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do that!

Answer (score 0):

/wp-content/themes/builds/development/style.css" />

Use get_site_url function for path

Answer (score 0):

The default style.css file for any WordPress theme must be included in the root of your custom theme. In this case it would need to be included in the "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Blog" directory.

That stylesheet must also contain the [required markup declared at the top of the file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet). Then this file must also be referenced in the head of the WordPress template markup, either dynamically using a function (preferred) or written directly in the head.

You can include additional stylesheets, other than the default theme stylesheet, using the [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function.